# Magento 2.3 + PWA DevServer Url not working

Tags: node.js, magento2, progressive-web-apps, yarnpkg, venia

We have successfully completed the configuration for PWA Venia theme using [Magento provided tutorial](https://magento-research.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/)

We got a confirmation like :

[image]

When we checked in the /etc/hosts file we see an entry for https://magento-venia-concept-eyiy4.local.pwadev:9117/, But we are unsure how to browse this url to view the Venia PWA theme.

We get "magento-venia-concept-eyiy4.local.pwadev’s server IP address could not be found." in the browser.

Please guide me the steps after above so we can browse and see the PWA setup we completed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you are unsure? What happens when you visit that url in your browser?

Comment: nothing we get error "magento-venia-concept-eyiy4.local.pwadev’s server IP address could not be found."

Comment: Did you find any solution @SunilVerma